# How to perform multiple, sequential transformations in one XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, sequential

I have to perform two transformations over an XML document, first I need to modify it and then I need to sort the result of the previous modification.

The XML document is as follows:

```xml
<root>
    <s>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>
                    <f1>1</f1>
                    <f2>0004</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>1</f1>
                    <f2>003x</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>0</f1>
                    <f2>0002</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>1</f1>
                    <f2>0001</f2>
                </c>
            </b>
        </a>
    </s>
    <s>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>
                    <f1>0</f1>
                    <f2>0006</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>0</f1>
                    <f2>005x</f2>
                </c>
            </b>
        </a>
    </s>
</root>
```

I have two XSLT stylesheets, one for each transformation, they work well if executed separately, I mean in two steps, apply the first one and then apply the second one over the result of the first one.

This is the first stylesheet (value modification transformation):

```xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//f2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ends-with(.,'x')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('0', .)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This other is the second one (substructure sorting):

```xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root/s/a/b">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="f1"/>
                <xsl:sort select="f2"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of these two stylesheets applied to the XML document is:

```xml
<root>
    <s>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>
                    <f1>0</f1>
                    <f2>0002</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>1</f1>
                    <f2>0001</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>1</f1>
                    <f2>0003x</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>1</f1>
                    <f2>0004</f2>
                </c>
            </b>
        </a>
    </s>
    <s>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>
                    <f1>0</f1>
                    <f2>0005x</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>0</f1>
                    <f2>0006</f2>
                </c>
            </b>
        </a>
    </s>
</root>
```

This is the expected result and it is correct.

Now I need to merge them into only one XSLT stylesheet, to be executed in only one step, but my attempts so far can't get the same result, the second transformation is applied to the original XML document instead of the result of the first transformation.

This is XSLT stylesheet I'm trying:

```xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <!-- Begin first transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//f2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ends-with(.,'x')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('0', .)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- End first transformation -->
    <!-- Begin second transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="root/s/a/b">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="f1"/>
                <xsl:sort select="f2"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- End second transformation -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of this attempt on merged stylesheet is:

```xml
<root>
    <s>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>
                    <f1>0</f1>
                    <f2>0002</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>1</f1>
                    <f2>0001</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>1</f1>
                    <f2>0004</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>1</f1>
                    <f2>0003x</f2>
                </c>
            </b>
        </a>
    </s>
    <s>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>
                    <f1>0</f1>
                    <f2>0006</f2>
                </c>
                <c>
                    <f1>0</f1>
                    <f2>0005x</f2>
                </c>
            </b>
        </a>
    </s>
</root>
```

The problem with this result is that the 'c' substructures which values of field f2 ending with 'x' are in the wrong positions.

Even if I try another copy template like the first one just before the sorting template the result is still not the desired. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help me.

Sorry if this question is too long, I tried to make shorter but it lead to misunderstandings.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have two separate XSLT stylesheets and you want to chain them, the cleanest solution is to use a language that supports that, for XSLT 3.0 you can do it from XSLT 3.0 as XPath 3.1 has a function `fn:transform` that allows you to apply an XSLT and of course XPath 3.1 then is powerful enough to chain two or more XSLTs (e.g. with `fold-left`). With earlier versions of XSLT I would consider the host language like Java or C# or Python to chain the stylesheets. If you want to edit the code and merge them to have two processing steps use modes.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: Thanks. I'll check if my system supports XSLT 3.0 and if so I'll try to learn how to do what you mention.

Comment: The iuse of `ends-with` suggests you are at least using an XSLT 2 processor. Anyway, for the failure to combine the templates it would also help if you show and explain the result you want and show and explain how the result of your attempt fails exactly; given that you have only two templates plus the identity transformation where one template transforms `f2` elements and the other `b` elements it is not quite clear what fails.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact result you expect to get (AFAICT, you are trying to produce an XML fragment with multiple `b` elements without a single root element). Also clarify which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have edited the question, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: I have confirmed that my system supports XSLT 3.0. The stylesheets seem to be working fine disregarding the version declaration, with version=1.0 and version=2.0 the result is the same.

Comment: @juankinspain The result in your specific case may be the same, but the processor does NOT "disregard" the declared version - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#backwards

Comment: See my answer on chaining stylesheets with `fn:transform` and `fold-left` in XSLT 3 (and where higher-order functions/fold-left is supported, i.e. Saxon 10 and higher, SaxonJS 2 and others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine the 2 transforms simply as:

*(edited)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="first-transformation">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="first"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-transformation"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="f2[ends-with(., 'x')]" mode="first">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('0', .)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="c">
            <xsl:sort select="f1"/>
            <xsl:sort select="f2"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering, not sure about the result of your stylesheet, is returning only 'b' substructures. I have edited the question in order to clarify what I need.

Comment: This produces the desired result, although I don't understand how. I suppose the mode attributes determine the order of execution at runtime and not the order in which each template is put into the stylesheet. Thanks.

Comment: This transformation is performed in 2 steps: in the first step, the `$first-transformation` variable is populated by applying templates with `mode="first"` or `mode="#all"` to the original XML. The final result is produced by applying templates with no mode or `mode="#all"` to the result of the first step. The order in which the templates appear in the stylesheet has no significance (in this case). Hopefully this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 3.0, if you want to chain a sequence of separate stylesheets, you can do that using `fold-left` and `transform` e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

<xsl:param name="stylesheet-uris" as="xs:string*" select="'sheet1.xsl', 'sheet2.xsl'"/>

<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template" match="/">
  <xsl:sequence 
    select="fold-left($stylesheet-uris, ., function($node, $xslt) {
               transform(
                 map {
                   'stylesheet-location' : $xslt,
                   'source-node' : $node
                 }
               )?output
            })"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have tested this and it works, I would like to also accept this answer as correct but unfortunately I can accept only one. I decided too accept the other answer as correct because it is a bit more close to what I was attempting to achieve. @Martin Honnen: Thanks anyway, it is an awesome solution.